# Random comment on random post in wordpress

Tags: php, random, wordpress

I can't find a solution to this idea. I'm trying to show in the frontpage, with a widget, a random post of one category and a random comment of the same post is showing.

I'm using RokSprocket to show in an stilysn way the post, with a carrousel and so on... when I insert the code for a random comment I get a random comment of "ALL" the posts, not only of that very same post.

```
<?php $post_id = "ITEMID" ;
$comments = get_comments("post_id=$post_id&status=approve");
if ($comments) { $ndx = mt_rand(1,sizeof($comments)) - 1;
$comment = $comments[$ndx]; }?>
<div class="iruzkina">
<div class="irudia">
<?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 64 ); ?>
<span class="karma">
<?php echo $comment->comment_karma; ?>
</span>
</div>
<span class="iruzkina-testua">
<?php echo $comment->comment_content; ?>
</span>
<span class="egilea">
<?php echo $comment->comment_author; ?>
</span>
</div>
```

So the problem is that the "ITEMID" shall be the correct post_id number.

The way RokSprocket inserts the title and so is this

```
<?php if ($item->getPrimaryLink()) : ?>
 <a href="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $item->getTitle(); ?></a>
<?php else: ?>
```

Does anyone has a clue about it?

Comment: Well... I tried a workaround and added this, so RokSprocket is not longer necessary

Answer (score 0):

Well... I tried a workaround and added this, so RokSprocket is not longer necessary

```
<?php $post_id = $id ;
$comments = get_comments("post_id=$post_id&status=approve");
if ($comments) { $ndx = mt_rand(1,sizeof($comments)) - 1;
$comment = $comments[$ndx]; }?>
<div class="galdera">
<?php $izenburua = $comment->comment_post_ID;?>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($izenburua); ?>" class="izenburua">
<?php echo get_the_title( $izenburua ); ?> </a>
</div>
<div class="iruzkina">
<?php $egilea = $comment->comment_author_email; ?>
<div class="irudia">
<?php echo get_avatar( $egilea, 64 ); ?> 
</div>
<span class="karma">
<?php echo $comment->comment_karma; ?>
</span>
<span class="iruzkina-testua">
<?php echo $comment->comment_content; ?>
</span>
<span class="egilea">
<?php echo $comment->comment_author; ?>
</span>
</div>
```